# Parsing webhook using emacs-web-server

Tags: github, emacs, webserver

I'm using [`emacs-web-server`](https://github.com/eschulte/emacs-web-server) and [`ngrok`](https://ngrok.com) to receive Webhooks from GitHub. With regards to set up, I am manually firing requests from Github via the Redeliver button on Github's site:

[image: Sent from GitHub]

I am using the following code to handle the request from GitHub:

```
(ws-start
 '(((:POST . ".*") .
    (lambda (request)
      (with-slots (process headers pending) request
        (print "# pending start #")
        (print pending)))))
 9005)
```

An example `emacs-web-server POST` can be found here:
http://eschulte.github.io/emacs-web-server/POST-Echo.html#POST-Echo

It is coming in just fine, and `print`ing of `pending` shows the following in my *Messages* buffer:

[image: Request]

But I'm having trouble isolating the payload in a variable (that is, all content following the double lines break: `{\"ref\"..` and on). I have tried several regexes; These all seem to work when I use them in a scratch buffer with a pasted copy of the pending variable but do not work in the actual payload scenario. Presumably the `^M`s have something to do with this, as they are not there when the content is pasted into another buffer. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circling back as @Rick77 recently inquired.

I was able to get request handling/parsing to work by manually reading the response.

However more recently I faced a similar scenario (except for outgoing requests) and have since found using the 'request and 'json libraries to be a simpler approach:

```
(require 'json)
(require 'request)

(defun get-response-data (url)
  (let* ((res (request url :sync t))
         (data (request-response-data res)))
    (json-read-from-string data)))
```

https://github.com/ryancrum/json.el

https://tkf.github.io/emacs-request/

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you have a string containing an HTTP request in which the body is a JSON document.  You most definitely don't want to parse that yourself with regexes.

The common procedure in situations like this is to first parse the HTTP request using a suitable library, get the body from the result (using a method call of the library), and finally parse the JSON document in the body using another suitable library.

I've done this for example in Clojure for receiving webhook calls from GitHub, I have never used Emacs for this kind of stuff, though.

A quick search for HTTP request parsers and JSON parsers yielded https://tkf.github.io/emacs-request/ and  http://tess.oconnor.cx/2006/03/json.el .   Maybe they are useful for you.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for the thoughtful response. My understanding is that `emacs-web-server` should in fact be doing the request parsing, as it is for simple POST requests. I am not particularly familiar with the common lisp object system, but it seems odd that the interface with which to access the payload is via the `pending` slot.

Comment: Hi! @AesopHimself I have a similar problem and I found your question: did you manage to solve it by chance? I would have expected emacs webserver to handle the request on its own :(

Answer (score 1):

[receiver.el](https://github.com/leppert/receiver) is an Emacs library I wrote to accomplish what I believe you're looking to do, but using [elnode](https://github.com/nicferrier/elnode) as the web server and [beame-insta-ssl](https://github.com/beameio/beame-insta-ssl) as the tunnel. It'd be easy to modify it to use ngrok instead of beame-insta-ssl and a pull request to that effect would be welcomed.